# Regular expression to match not the beginning/end of a line

Tags: regex, eclipse, lookbehind

I would like a regular expression to match only " that

- don't come at the start of a line or after white space at the start of a line
- don't come at the end of a line or before white space at the end of a line

I guess I need to use lookbehind and lookahead.

So matches the " in

```
zfgjhsgaf jhsa gd " gjhygf" hgf
```

But not in

```
"gjhgjkgjhgjhgkk"

      "dfsdfsdf"
```

Comment: Just floundered around trying to use lookbehind and lookahead - asthey're not supported in javascript regex I've never used them before and not sure excatly how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eclipse, try finding by this regex:

```
(?<!^\s*)"(?!\s*$)
```

And replacing with:

```
\"
```

Comment: Note that variable-width lookbehind assertions have pretty poor support across implementations. PHP and JavaScript don't support them.

Comment: I'm looking for a regex to use in my IDE (eclipse) in order to escape non-line-ending " in a text file. D'you have any ideas about getting the same effect for end of line?

Comment: Of all things... well, does my regex work? (I edited it to include the end of the line.)

Comment: Have tweaked it to work for multiline json too (though may not always work)
(?<!(^|:)\s*)"(?!(\s*$|:|,))

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
^\s*[^"].*".*[^"]\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

See this here

```
(?<!^)"(?!\s*$)
```

[at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tq0a)

It works not for the whitespace after beginning of the line. As BoltClock mentioned, variable length look behind is supported only by few engines (I know only .net).

If you use a regex that support it, you can use

```
(?<!^.*)"(?!\s*$)
```

A good documentation for look ahead/behind is here in the [perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*"?.*\S.*(").*?\S.*?"?\s*$
```

Which supports matching '  "foo"bar"  ' assuming that is something that you want to find.

Oh, and it only matches if $1 is set

Answer (score 0):

I think whis re is expressive enougth :

```
^\s*\S+.*innertext.*\S+\s*$
```